# How to retrieve specific data in a mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Im trying to pull specific data from a mongo db collection. I'm finding an invoice by a specific ID, then I want to pull specific data from that invoice (invoiceDetails, invoiceCost, etc ). I keep getting undefined objects with what I've tried.

I'm using `find()` to fetch invoices by id, then I'm trying to get specific properties inside the invoice:

```
router.get('/searchbar/:id', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  let userId = req.params.id
  Invoice.find({'user': userId})
    .then(invoice => {
        res.status(200).json({
          userDetails: invoice.userDetails,
          invoiceCost: invoice.Cost
        })         
    });   
});
```

Why are userDetails and invoiceCost both returning undefined?

Comment: Can you add your Invoice model code to the question?

Comment: Because `find()` returns an **array** and not a singular object. i.e `var invoice = [{ userdetails: "A" }]` would mean that `console.log(invoice.userdetails)` would be `undefined`.  Using `console.log(invoice[0].userdetails)` however returns the value. The real point here being you did not expect an *array*, so instead use `findOne()`, which will actually return just the singular object you were expecting instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Invoice.find({'user': userId})` to `Invoice.find({'user': userId}, 'userDetails Cost')` as explained in the [Mongoose Docs > Model.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)